# How to adjust size of x-axis font using R?

Tags: r, bar-chart, plotly

Using the following R code, I made a plot in R Studio. As you see, only part of the texts due to x-axis are shown. How can I show the whole term?
Also, When I plot the data, the data is plotted with regard to alphabetic or numeric order not with respect to the order I define the data in the array. So, as you see I added numbers from 0 to 9 to the beginning of the names of the x-axis texts.

```
library(plotly)
p<- plot_ly(
          x= c("0CI-37. Craft labor turnover", "1CI-35. Craft labor quality 
             issues", "2CI-2. Impact of required approvals",
            "3CI-26. Impact of project location", "4CI-4.  no. of joint- 
             venture entities",
            "5CI-32. Timinig of change orders", "6CI-31. Magnitude of change 
             orders", 
            "7CI-36. Frequency of workarounds", "8CI-5. no. of executive 
             oversight above PMT","9CI-14. Peak  no.of FTE design"),
           y= c(0.58, 5.81, 8.13, 9.88, 9.88, 8.13, 7.55, 5.81, 5.81, 0.58),
            type="bar",
            color= I("lightblue"),
        name="Contractor"
)
p

p2<- add_trace(p,
        x= c("0CI-37. Craft labor turnover", "1CI-35. Craft labor quality 
            issues", "2CI-2. Impact of required approvals", 
            "3CI-26. Impact of project location", "4CI-4.  no. of joint- 
             venture entities",
             "5CI-32. Timinig of change orders", "6CI-31. Magnitude of change 
             orders", 
             "7CI-36. Frequency of workarounds", "8CI-5. no. of executive 
             oversight above PMT","9CI-14. Peak  no.of FTE design"),
        y= c(13.01, 8.28, 10.65, 10.65, 5.91, 4.14, 7.1, 6.5, 5.32, 1.77),
           color= I("lightgreen"),
           name="Owner"
)
p2

p3<- add_trace(p2,
           x= c("0CI-37. Craft labor turnover", "1CI-35. Craft labor quality 
                 issues", "2CI-2. Impact of required approvals", 
                "3CI-26. Impact of project location", "4CI-4.  no. of joint- 
                 venture entities",
                "5CI-32. Timinig of change orders", "6CI-31. Magnitude of 
                 change orders", 
                "7CI-36. Frequency of workarounds", "8CI-5. no. of executive 
                 oversight above PMT","9CI-14. Peak  no.of FTE design"),
           y= c(4.73, 11.83, 5.91, 4.73, 2.95, 4.14, 3.55, 1.77, 4.73, 2.36),
                 color= I("orange"),
                name="Consultant"
)
p3
```

[image]

Comment: [Google knows all](https://plot.ly/r/axes/)!  See under "Style Axes Titles and Ticks Labels"

Comment: Good that Google is not aggressive!!

Comment: Their motto is "don't be evil", so I think we're ok until that changes

Comment: `p3 <-  add_trace(blah) %>%  layout(xaxis = list(tickfont = list(size = 'specify size here')))`

Comment: I was getting the same error when I was using `layout()` as a parameter inside `add_trace()`. Using it outside add_trace() with `%>%` solved it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting axis label font sizes can be done by:

```
p3 <- add_trace(blah) %>% layout(
                                 xaxis = list(tickfont = list(size = 'specify size here')), 
                                 yaxis = list(tickfont = list(size = 'specify size here'))
                                 )
```

New version of plotly requires adding layout() outside the plot, using %>%, and not as a parameter of the plot function.